# TypeScript operator precedence table (or what's the precedence of Type Assertions?)

Tags: typescript

I guess operators exist in JavaScript use their original precedence, but new constructs like Type Assertions (i.e. `<Type> expr`) and arrow function expressions are less clear.

It will be helpful if there's an official table somewhere.

Comment: The specification contains information on how certain amiguities are resolved.

Comment: @IngoBürk I have read the spec, but it is not very clear to me how type assertions interact with property access and function expressions. E.g., what does this expression mean `<T> a.b`?

Comment: 4.13 states that type assertions are applied on an (entire) unary expression. Hence, I would expect that `<T> a.b` is equivalent to `<T> (a.b)`. And a quick test does confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have supplied some examples of Type Assertions below that will hopefully shine some light on this feature for you.

The interesting bit is that *if a set of parentheses has an affect on the scope of a type assertion, the parentheses are removed by type erasure during compilation*. This means that example `b` below results in `(x)` in the JavaScript, whereas example `c` results in simply `x`.

The only reason to use parentheses to set the scope of the type assertion is when you want to apply to a part of the right-hand expression, in which case you would place the type assertion inside of the parentheses, as shown in example `e`.

```
interface SomeType {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

var x = {};

var a: SomeType = <SomeType> x;

// Note, when brackets do not affect 
// type assertions they will be left in the output
var b: SomeType = <SomeType> (x);

// When brackets affect type assertions,
// they are erased along with the type information
var c: SomeType = (<SomeType> x);

// Two errors:
// - SomeType is not assignable to d
// - Property id does not exist on x
var d: number = <SomeType> x.id;

// Brackets are useful here:
var e: number = (<SomeType> x).id;

// More complex example
var func = () => {
    return x; // return type is {}
};
var f: SomeType = <SomeType> func();
```

Comment: Okay, so it matches the cast operator in C-like languages. However, I just want to point out another thing: function application binds more closely than type assertion, so the following does not type: `interface FunType { (): string }
          
var x: string= <FunType> function() {return undefined;}();`. This again matches C, but is unclear solely based on the spec.