# How to get the value of time element in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, datetime

I have a time input element in HTML and I want its value as a number in Typescript. In Javascript we can do that by
`var time = document.getElementById("time").valueAsNumber;`

But in Typescript it is throwing an error that **Property 'valueAsNumber' does not exist on type 'HTMLTimeElement'** after I wrote this code,

`var time = <HTMLTimeElement>document.getElementById("time").valueAsNumber;`

What do I do?

Comment: ```parserInt(documment.getElementById("time").value)```

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`HTMLTimeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement) values (for [`<time>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) tags) *actually* don't have `valueAsNumber` properties, you can believe TypeScript compiler on that. It seems like you really need to use [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) interface (for [`<input type="time">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) elements) instead:

```
var time = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("time")).valueAsNumber;
```

---

Another issue is that you have fallen to TypeScript's operator precendence trap: the property accessor operator (`object.prop`) has higher priority over type cast operator (`<Type> value`). Your expression therefore reads as this:

```
var time = <HTMLTimeElement> (document.getElementById("time").valueAsNumber);
```

… whereas you need this:

```
var time = (<HTMLTimeElement> document.getElementById("time")).valueAsNumber;
```

*(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316948/4554883 for details.)*

Comment: the OP fell in 2 traps, actually :) But you are right, with the `<type>` assertion syntax one needs brackets when immediately accessing a property after asserting.

Answer (score 1):

You made an incorrect assumption:

That `<input type="time" />` translates to an `HTMLTimeElement` interface. The latter represents a special element with the tag `<time>` used in semantic markup containing machine-readable date & time as its value under the `dateTime` property (see the MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement)).

What you needed instead was the `HTMLInputElement` interface which is *shared* by all `<input>` elements, the `valueAsNumber` will be present on the interface:

```ts
const { valueAsNumber } = <HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("time")); //OK, valueAsNumber is number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/N4KABBYMYPYHYGcAuZhgG4EMA2BXApgIIIByuAtgEb4BOYAvmALxgA8AEgCoCyAMgJJwADriQBRbPnL44SAHwAKACYwoFGUgB0Ac3zjJ02QCEAnvyUKAREgCW0ywEoHAbjAB6NwHkA0gBoMOATEZFS0YDYIYHAU1DQg9EA)

Comment: @NisargKudgunti - NP :) `<time>` is a more obscure tag so it's not unreasonable to expect that it might be the interface you are looking for with `<input type="time" />`. The rule of thumb is that if you have an input, it will be a subtype of `HTMLInputElement` interface regardless of type.